# Android get firebase callback data during onCreate

Tags: android, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I've run into a bit of an interesting problem and I'm not really sure how to proceed.

The app that I'm writing has a theme that changes according to what state the user is in. In order to implement this and persist the state across the app closing, I've stored the state in sharedPreferences and retrieved it in the `onCreate()` method, then called `setTheme(R.style.myTheme)` before the `super.onCreate()` call which as far as I'm aware is the only way to dynamically set the theme for an activity without restarting the entire activity.

I now want to store the state variable in Firebase and retrieve it at runtime to update the theme accordingly. This way a user could open the app on a different device, sign in and have the interface be themed correctly. The way that I've been retrieving data from firebase so far is by implementing an interface called `DatabaseCallback` on each of the classes that needs to access Firebase data and calling a method from `DatabaseCallback` to inform the class that the data that it needs is available.

Here's an example of that:

```
public void getUserByUid(String uid, final DatabaseCallback c) {
    DatabaseReference userRef = db.getReference("users/" + uid);
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            c.onGetUser(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is where the problem arises. When I call the `getUserByUid()` method in my `onCreate()`, the callback isn't made until *after* `onCreate()` finishes which stops me from being able to update the theme. Any thoughts on either a better implementation for getting data/a different way to update the theme *without* restarting the activity?

Comment: does your app have splash? or any activity before your theme-changing activity? if so, why not place listener on it (activity before) then place intent inside `onDataChanged()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your firebase listener in either intent service or Async task then save it to sharedPreferences, then you can change theme the way it was being loaded offline.

Comment: Ok.. then you can get data from Firebase on background thread might be through AsyncTask and call startactivity once the loading is finished. i.e OnFinished in case of AsyncTask